# Нужен мануал по работе со звуком в AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, php

Можно ли во flash записывать звук, а потом только целым файлом отправлять на сервер. Потоковая передача не подходит, хотя инфу по ним я нашел. Мой хостер не согласится больше чем на only php.

P.S.: Я новичок в работе с flash (вернее сказать только сел изучать его). Поэтому вопрос может показаться некорректным. Нужны справки на мануалы. Но мануалы нужны именно по вопросу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раньше этим тоже интересовался, вот [ссылка](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/create-a-useful-audio-recorder-app-in-actionscript-3/). Записывает звук с микрофона и даёт скачать на комп. Остальное нужно искать [здесь](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d22.html).